# Не сохраняется сущность в базу при использовании Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

Всем привет, не могу разобраться почему не сохраняется сущность DateException в базу данных при вызове метода контроллера addExceptionToEvent. Контроллер возвращает статус 200, но в базу добавляется только сущность Event, игнорируя её связь с DateException.
Подскажите,пожалуйста, что я упустил?
У меня есть бд,которая имеет следующую структуру

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Create hibernate_sequence
-- -----------------------------------------------------

DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS hibernate_sequence;
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 20
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE hibernate_sequence
  OWNER TO viktor_kulygin;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `event`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  event_type VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  event_location VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  event_start_date TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
  event_end_date TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
  event_time VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  event_cost INT NULL,
  event_link VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `date_exception`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS date_exception (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  event_date_ex TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
  event_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, event_id)
  ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_date_exception_event
  FOREIGN KEY (event_id)
  REFERENCES event (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;

CREATE INDEX fk_date_exception_event_idx ON date_exception (event_id ASC);
```

Файл **Event**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "event_type")
    private String eventType;

    @Column(name = "event_location")
    private String eventLocation;

    @Column(name = "event_start_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/dd/mm H:m:s:S")
    private LocalDateTime eventStartDate;

    @Column(name = "event_end_date")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/dd/mm H:m:s:S")
    private LocalDateTime eventEndDate;

    @Column(name = "event_time")
    private String eventTime;

    @Column(name = "event_cost")
    private long eventCost;

    @Column(name = "event_link")
    private String eventLink;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "event")
    private Set<DateException> dateExceptions;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Event(String eventType, String eventLocation, LocalDateTime eventStartDate, LocalDateTime eventEndDate, String eventTime, long eventCost, String eventLink) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.eventLocation = eventLocation;
        this.eventStartDate = eventStartDate;
        this.eventEndDate = eventEndDate;
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
        this.eventCost = eventCost;
        this.eventLink = eventLink;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getEventLocation() {
        return eventLocation;
    }

    public void setEventLocation(String eventLocation) {
        this.eventLocation = eventLocation;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEventStartDate() {
        return eventStartDate;
    }

    public void setEventStartDate(LocalDateTime eventStartDate) {
        this.eventStartDate = eventStartDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEventEndDate() {
        return eventEndDate;
    }

    public void setEventEndDate(LocalDateTime eventEndDate) {
        this.eventEndDate = eventEndDate;
    }

    public String getEventTime() {
        return eventTime;
    }

    public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }

    public long getEventCost() {
        return eventCost;
    }

    public void setEventCost(long eventCost) {
        this.eventCost = eventCost;
    }

    public String getEventLink() {
        return eventLink;
    }

    public void setEventLink(String eventLink) {
        this.eventLink = eventLink;
    }

    public Set<DateException> getDateExceptions() {
        return dateExceptions;
    }

    public void setDateExceptions(Set<DateException> dateExceptions) {
        this.dateExceptions = dateExceptions;
    }
}
```

Файл **DateException**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "date_exception")
public class DateException {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "event_date_ex")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/dd/mm H:m:s:S")
    private LocalDateTime eventDateEx;

    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Event event;

    public DateException() {
    }

    public DateException(LocalDateTime eventDateEx) {
        this.eventDateEx = eventDateEx;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEventDateEx() {
        return eventDateEx;
    }

    public void setEventDateEx(LocalDateTime eventDateEx) {
        this.eventDateEx = eventDateEx;
    }

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

**Репозитории**

```
public interface DateExceptionRepository extends CrudRepository<DateException, Long> {
}

public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    Page<Event> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Сервис**

```
public interface EventService {

    Event getEventById(Long eventId);
    Event createEvent(String eventType, String eventLocation, LocalDateTime eventStartDate, LocalDateTime eventEndDate, String eventTime, long eventCost, String eventLink);
    void deleteEventById(Long eventId);
    Event addExceptionToEvent(Event event, LocalDateTime eventDateEx);
    Page<Event> findAllEvents(PageRequest pageRequest);
}

@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @Override
    public Event getEventById(Long eventId) {
        return eventRepository.findOne(eventId);
    }

    @Override
    public Event createEvent(String eventType, String eventLocation, LocalDateTime eventStartDate, LocalDateTime eventEndDate, String eventTime, long eventCost, String eventLink) {
        Event event = new Event(eventType, eventLocation, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventTime, eventCost, eventLink);
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEventById(Long eventId) {
        eventRepository.delete(eventId);
    }

    @Override
    public Event addExceptionToEvent(Event event, LocalDateTime eventDateEx) {
        DateException dateException = new DateException(eventDateEx);
        Set<DateException> dateExceptionSet = new HashSet<>();
        dateExceptionSet.add(dateException);
        event.setDateExceptions(dateExceptionSet);
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Event> findAllEvents(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        Page<Event> events = eventRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        return events;
    }
}
```

**И контроллер**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/event")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;

    @Autowired
    DateExceptionRepository dateExceptionRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEvent(@PathVariable("id") Long eventId) {
        Event event = eventService.getEventById(eventId);
        if (event == null) {
            return getErrorResponseBody(ApplicationErrorTypes.EVENT_ID_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(convert(event), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteEvent(@PathVariable("id") Long eventId) {
        Event event = eventService.getEventById(eventId);
        if (event == null) {
            return getErrorResponseBody(ApplicationErrorTypes.EVENT_ID_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        eventService.deleteEventById(eventId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEvent(@RequestBody EventDTO eventDTO) {
        LocalDateTime startEventDate = eventDTO.getEventStartDate() == null ? null : eventDTO.getEventStartDate().getLocalDateData();
        LocalDateTime endEventDate = eventDTO.getEventEndDate() == null ? null : eventDTO.getEventEndDate().getLocalDateData();
        Event event = eventService.createEvent(eventDTO.getEventType(), eventDTO.getEventLocation(), startEventDate,
                endEventDate, eventDTO.getEventTime(), eventDTO.getEventCost(), eventDTO.getEventLink());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(convert(event), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/addException", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addExceptionToEvent(@PathVariable("id") Long eventId, @RequestBody DateExceptionDTO dateExceptionDTO) {
        Event event = eventService.getEventById(eventId);
        if (event == null) {
            return getErrorResponseBody(ApplicationErrorTypes.EVENT_ID_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        LocalDateTime eventDateEx = dateExceptionDTO.getEventDateEx() == null ? null : dateExceptionDTO.getEventDateEx().getLocalDateData();
        event = eventService.addExceptionToEvent(event, eventDateEx);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(convert(event), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAllPagination", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllEventsPagination(@RequestParam("page") Long page, @RequestParam("pageSize") Long pageSize) {
        Page<Event> events = eventService.findAllEvents(new PageRequest(page.intValue(), pageSize.intValue(), new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id")));
        List<Event> resultListOfEvents = events.getContent();
        if (resultListOfEvents.size() == 0) {
            return getErrorResponseBody(ApplicationErrorTypes.EVENTS_LIST_IS_EMPTY_OR_PAGE_NOT_EXIST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(convert(resultListOfEvents), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private EventDTO convert(Event model) {
        return (model == null) ? null : new EventDTO(model);
    }

    private EventListDTO convert(List<Event> dbModel) {
        return (dbModel == null) ? null : new EventListDTO(dbModel);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseBody> getErrorResponseBody(ApplicationErrorTypes errorType) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseBody(errorType), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить каскад к связи:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "event", cascade = {DETACH,MERGE,PERSIST,REFRESH}) 
private Set<DateException> dateExceptions;
```

Comment: Добавление каскада связи помогло,но не полностью, запись в таблице date_exception появилась, но поле event_id в нем, у соответсвующей записи равно null

Comment: После добавления каскада связи поправил немного метод @Override
    public Event addExceptionToEvent(Event event, LocalDateTime eventDateEx) {
        DateException dateException = new DateException(eventDateEx);
        dateException.setEvent(event);
        Set<DateException> dateExceptionSet = new HashSet<>();
        dateExceptionSet.add(dateException);
        event.setDateExceptions(dateExceptionSet);
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    } И теперь все заработало как надо,спасибо)